# PHP: Combine arrays and then sort

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am new to PHP and trying to combine reviews of multiple products to then sort them by date.

I am able to access all the reviews of products in the specific category but rather than them being combined, product 1 for example will sort it's reviews then below that product 2's, etc etc:

```
Product 1 21/12/2019
Product 1 23/12/2019
Product 2 20/12/2019
Product 2 21/12/2019
Product 3 21/12/2019
```

When really I would like to combine the results:

```
Product 2 20/12/2019
Product 1 21/12/2019
Product 2 21/12/2019
Product 3 21/12/2019
Product 1 23/12/2019
```

I currently get all the product ids in the specific category with this:

```
$reviews = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_reviews);
```

I then use the product ids to get the reviews for each product and then assign the values to be used:

```
foreach ($reviews as $result) {
    $reviews = $this->model_catalog_review->getReviewsByProductId($result['product_id']);

    foreach ($reviews as $result) {
        $data['reviews'][] = array(
            'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
            'date_added' => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($result['date_added']))
            );
     }  
}
```

Printing the array `print_r($data['reviews']);` outside the foreach loops is giving me this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [product_id] => 1 [date_added] => 23/12/2019 ) 
[1] => Array ( [product_id] => 1 [date_added] => 23/10/2019 ) 
[2] => Array ( [product_id] => 1 [date_added] => 21/10/2019 ) 
[3] => Array ( [product_id] => 2 [date_added] => 28/11/2019 ) 
[4] => Array ( [product_id] => 2 [date_added] => 29/10/2019 ) 
[5] => Array ( [product_id] => 2 [date_added] => 28/10/2019 ) 
[6] => Array ( [product_id] => 2 [date_added] => 28/10/2019 ) 
[7] => Array ( [product_id] => 2 [date_added] => 27/10/2019 ) )
```

Is there a way to achieve combining the results within the foreach loop? So that instead of it being all the product 1's together and then product 2's together it merges them.

I have tried using the usort function to compare each date_added value and then sort. This works for sorting for example oldest to latest or latest to oldest but rather than combining all reviews then sorting it sorts product 1's first then product 2's, etc.

```
function sorta($a, $b) {
    if ($a['date_added'] == $b['date_added']) return 0;
    return ($a['date_added'] < $b['date_added']) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Then inside the foreach:

```
usort($data['reviews'], 'sorta');
```

And I have also tried:

```
array_multisort( array_column($reviews, "date_added"), SORT_ASC, $reviews);
```

With no luck. Any help or pointers would be great!

Comment: I don't understand the word 'combine' in this context.

Comment: Does the sorting itself work? What is the issue?

Comment: Why do you have nested loops? And the inner loop is redefining `$reviews`.

Comment: If you want to sort the final results, you should be sorting `$data['reviews']`, not `$reviews`.

Comment: @Strawberry I am not able to sort all the reviews together, instead I am sorting product 1's reviews then product 2's reviews. But if the latest review is from Product 2 I would like that to be the first in all reviews ( 1 and 2 ) rather than the first of product 2's reviews. I am unsure if this is because I am creating multiple arrays? Hope I have explained better!

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your help! `usort($data['reviews'], 'sorta');` for example with this I am able to sort each products reviews in latest or oldest but I am unable to combine all the reviews of all products then do the same. Is this due to my structure - two nested loops? One was to loop through products and then the next to assign the values.

Comment: @Beth It looks like your loop is combining all the reviews. The nested loops does seem correct, it's just confusing to use the same variables in both loops.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure if this is possible but may explain it better. The print_r is showing three Array ( ), the first empty, the second with product 1's reviews and the third with product 2's reviews. Is it possible to merge the three in php? So that I can then sort them within a single Array ( ) or does it not work like that?

Comment: You're printing `$reviews` during the loop, not `$data['reviews']` after the entire thing is done.

Comment: @Barmar Okay the array is now giving me more what I expected! Thank you! I have updated my question with the new results. I have tried the usort with $data['reviews'] outside the foreach loops, it does give different results to when it is inside but again I'm unable to combine the product id's, it is able to sort them though - oldest to newest for individual id then the next id, etc. Any idea what is causing the grouping by ID rather than it just sorting the whole array?

Comment: If you want to be able to sort dates as string, they should be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, not `DD/MM/YYYY`.